# ifstream object declared inside a function not working on release mode

Tags: c++

I am working on my first app that i´m actually going to give to someone else to use it, so i am trying to do the hole deploy process (on Qt), and create an installer after.

The problem is that a have a specific point in my code (i already discovered where), that it runs fine on Debug mode, but on Release i have no ideia what happens (it symply not run the specific function).

The problem is (just a simple example about the) that, if a declare an ifstream object in the main function, the release .exe runs just fine. When i put that object on a function, it doesnt work! I dont know what to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <reader.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <mrp.h>
#include <file_manager.h>
#include <string>
#include <facade_mrp.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void test()
{
    fstream f;                
    f.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Alexandre\\C++\\MRP\\build-MRP-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MinGW_32bit-Release\\Demandas.txt",ifstream::in);
    f.close();              

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test();                 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not see anything of [tag:qt] in your code

Comment: there is no way to tell where the problem is with this simplified code since you just opening and closing the file. but my guess is that you are trying to release `fstream f` object outside of the test function. `fstream f` would be deleted once the test function finishes execution. this would also explain why it would work when `fstream f` is placed within the main body instead of the function.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It crashes? Runs but doesn't produce the expected output? Something else? The code you've posted will do nothing other than attempting to briefly open a file and will complete whether the file exists or not. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, this IS  a minimal example, in which the problem occurs. If a run this simple code in Debug mode, all works fine, but in release, something went wrong and the code doest get to the end (in the release, for example, if a have a cout >> "hello" before  the retorn 0, i dont see the message on the screen, whreas, if a do not call the function (test), i do see the message.

Comment: So what _specifically_ happens differently with the code posted, when you build in release mode and run it? Does it not terminate normally? If you need an additional output line to see the difference, please add it and then describe what happens with _that_ code.

Comment: Did you try running in a debugger? If your program is crashing the debugger will normally tell you why

Comment: Yes...now, i´ve made the same program compiled under code::blocks, and the Release was fine! It appears something is happening only on Qt

Comment: Do you mean Qt Creator, the IDE? Because "Qt" in isolation means a bunch of cross-platform libraries you don't seem to be using, which is confusing people. If It's the Qt Creator IDE you have problems with, you should still be able to step through its release binary with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what you mean by: *"does not work"*. Does the program crash? Or just does it not read the contents of the file?

To troubleshoot a problem with `std::ifstream`, it's usually convenient to have a look at `.good()`, `.fail()` and `.eof()` member functions. Find out more about them [in the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good).

If the problem presents in Release configuration, but not in Debug, there are usually few common culprits you should look into:

- Release builds usually have `-O2` or `-O3` optimization levels enabled, while Debug builds don't.
- Release builds are usually stored in a different file system path than Debug builds (check relative paths).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, i changed the code to warn me about the the ifstream state ".good()", and again, in debug mode it accuses TRUE (all good), but in release, the program never exits the function and finishes the main.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce?